# Constructor error (JAVA)

Tags: java, constructor

So I was able to get my first constructor working, but not my second one for p2. For p2 I am trying to display (string, string, string, double, double, string, string). As it stands the code displays a error of "string cannot be converted to double", but I don't see whee I am doing that.

Here's my  code for my main.
        package studenthealthservices;

```
    public class Studenthealthservices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EMR p1 = new EMR("Colin","10-22-74");
        System.out.printf(p1.toString());

        EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache","98", "120", "stress", "Tylenol");
        System.out.printf(p2.toString());

    }}
```

Here is my code for my EMR class
        package studenthealthservices;

```
public class EMR {

    private String name;
    private String dob;
    private String rfv;
    private double bodyt;
    private double hr;
    private String diag;
    private String pmeds;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public EMR (String name, String dob) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
}
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public EMR (String name, String dob, String rfv, double bodyt, double hr,          String diag, String pmeds){
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.rfv = rfv;
        this.bodyt = bodyt;
        this.hr = hr;
        this.diag = diag;
        this.pmeds = pmeds;

    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getRfv() {
        return rfv;
    }

    public void setRfv(String rfv) {
        this.rfv = rfv;
    }

    public double getBodyt() {
        return bodyt;
    }

    public void setBodyt(double bodyt) {
        this.bodyt = bodyt;
    }

    public double getHr() {
        return hr;
    }

    public void setHr(double hr) {
        this.hr = hr;
    }

    public String getDiag() {
        return diag;
    }

    public void setDiag(String diag) {
        this.diag = diag;
    }

    public String getPmeds() {
        return pmeds;
    }

    public void setPmeds(String pmeds) {
        this.pmeds = pmeds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return"name :" + this.name +"Date of Birth:" + this.dob;
    }
}
```

Comment: When it comes to constructors (and methods) that need many parameters (a good rule of thumb is more than 3 or 4) it is preferable to group the parameters into a new type (and pass an instance of that type as a single parameter) or to use the builder pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"98"` is a `String`, not a `double`. You need to remove the quotes:

```
 EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache", 98, 120, "stress", "Tylenol");
```

Comment: Maybe even 98d/120d or 98D/120D (lower case `d` for native double & upper case `D` for the `Double`-Java-Class)

Answer (score 3):

When you are passing doubles to a method (ie a constructor), you cannot surround the double with quotes, otherwise they are strings.

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache","98", "120", "stress", "Tylenol");
```

which is invoking this constructor

```
public EMR (String name, String dob, String rfv, double bodyt, double hr,          String diag, String pmeds)
```

The values "98" and "120" are both Strings, not doubles for the parameters *bodyt* and *hr* respectively.

So, change this line to

```
EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache",98d, 120d, "stress", "Tylenol");
```

The suffix d for doubles is optional in this case. You could use 98 and 120.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look on this statement:

```
EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache","98", "120", "stress", "Tylenol");
```

And let's look on the constructor you are trying to call:

```
public EMR (String name, String dob, String rfv, double bodyt, double hr, String diag, String pmeds)
```

As you can see, constructor expects `bodyt` and `hr` to be of `double` type, but in your statement 98 and 120 has `String` type because of quotes (they are string literals). To make them `double` just remove quotes:

```
EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache",98, 120, "stress", "Tylenol");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing the values in the constructor of EMR for the object P2 you are passing 98 and 120 inside "".

```
EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache","98", "120", "stress", "Tylenol");
```

These are double values and should not be passed inside double quotes.Change your code to

```
EMR p2 = new EMR("Anquan","9-30-77", "stomach ache",98, 120, "stress", "Tylenol");
```